# Custom fields for event are not saving data

Tags: civievent, custom-fields

I want to use two custom fields for an event named `Friend Day`. One field is a dropdown the other is a Contact Reference.

I created a set of custom fields to be used for Participants where Event Name = `Friend Day`

When I register a participant for a `Friend Day` event, the custom fields display, and I can enter data into them and save the record.  However, when I open the record the custom fields are blank.  They did not save.  The regular participant fields for the event do save.

I get no errors.  Any suggestions appreciated on how to get the custom fields to save.

Comment: What is your civicrm version? are you using new participant form to register? Are you able to replicate on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/?

Comment: 1. We are running 5.68.0
2. Using "Add Event Registration" in the Participant tab.  I don't know what the "new participant form" is. 
3. Can't try to replicate since demo does not have admin rights to add custom fields.

Comment: Demo does allow you to add custom sets

Comment: I would suggest you to upgrade Civi to latest if possible

Answer (score 1):

Just noting I couldn't reproduce this on master (there are relevant recent code changes which may have fixed it) - are you able to try on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/

Comment: You are right. I upgrade to 5.71.1 and the error disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I was reported this issue 3 weeks ago [here](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/5005#note_159244) trusting that it would be related to the issue. But I have applied the PR without success. Therefore I think it is another regression.

Comment: Now that it is determined to be a bug of a released feature, how do I request that this issue gets resolved and know when it is?

Comment: Bug reporting is documented here https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/the-civicrm-community/bug-reporting. When you report the issue, I'll recommend you quote this SE question and the comments I made in the other similar issue https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/5005#note_159244

Comment: I upgrade to 5.71.1 and the error disappears.